How to find difference in values between the first and last day of the month in Google BigQuery?
I have a dataset that looks similar to this:



ID
Timestamp
Value 1
Value 2




1
2023-03-01 05:00:00 UTC
1200
3.2


1
2023-03-15 05:00:00 UTC
1400
2.4


1
2023-03-31 05:00:00 UTC
2000
2.8


2
2023-03-01 05:00:00 UTC
850
4


2
2023-03-15 05:00:00 UTC
1250
4.1


2
2023-03-31 05:00:00 UTC
3300
3.6



Where Value 1 and Value 2 are taken once a day at the same time for each ID.
Value 1 is an increasing number throughout the month while Value 2 is not.
I would like to find the difference in Value 1 between the last day and first day of every month for each ID.
Additionally, I would like to find the maximum Value 2 in every month for each ID.
Would it be easier to create two separate queries for each Value column or is there a way to do each task in the same query?

One query is better. Try select id,DATE_TRUNC(tmestamp, MONTH) AS mon,min(value1) min_value1,max(value1) max_value1,max(value2)max_value2 from your_table group by id,DATE_TRUNC(tmestamp, MONTH).

Assuming your table name is Table.
First create a CTE ProcessedInfo, with some additional colums to make our calculation easier, for which we will use Window Functions.
The three new colums are as follows:

Value1_FirstDay_Month - The Value1 value for the first day of each month of each year. For this will use FIRST_VALUE and partition by year and month, and then order by timestamp in ascending order
Value1_LastDay_Month - Same as the above, except its the Value1 for the last day of each month and year. We will use LAST_VALUE for this one, with same partitioning and ordering as the previous column.
Value2_Max_ID_Month - The maximum Value2, for each ID,Year and Month.

And then, a second CTE FinalResult, where we use the columns created in the first CTE, to calculate the desired result.

All colums of the original table.
Value1_Diff - The difference between Value1_LastDay_Month and Value1_FirstDay_Month
Value2_Max_ID_Month - Same as above. No calculation necessary as this is the desired result.

WITH ProcessedInfo AS (

SELECT
 *,
 FIRST_VALUE(Value1) OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) AS Value1_FirstDay_Month,
  LAST_VALUE(Value1) OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) AS Value1_LastDay_Month,
 MAX(Value2) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Timestamp)) AS Value2_Max_ID_Month
FROM Table
),

FinalResult AS (
 SELECT ID, Timestamp, Value1, Value2,
  (Value1_LastDay_Month - Value1_FirstDay_Month) AS Value1_Diff,
   Value2_Max_ID_Month
 FROM ProcessedInfo
)

SELECT * FROM FinalResult;


Use below (BigQuery) approach
select 
  id, date_trunc(date(ts), 
  month) as month, 
  max_by(value1, ts) - min_by(value1, ts) as value1_diff, 
  max(value2) as value2_max
from your_table
group by id, month    

if applied to sample data in your questions - output is


Really depends on how you want your output to appear. Regardless, one query is fine.
If you want to display all rows, then here's a method which uses window functions to calculate those values for you. In the example below, you may replace the substring() with your desired method to extract YYYYMM from your timestamp in Big Query.
select 
 id, 
 some_date, 
 value1,  
 value2, 
 max(value1) over (partition by id, substring(some_date, 1, 7)) - 
 min(value1) over (partition by id, substring(some_date, 1, 7)) as val1_diff, 
 max(value2) over (partition by id, substring(some_date, 1, 7)) as max_val2
from table1

But if you only want to display at the month and id level, then use this (again replacing substring with your desired method if you choose).
select 
 id, 
 substring(some_date, 1, 7) as yyyy_mm, 
 max(value1) - min(value1) as val1_diff, 
 max(value2) as max_val2
from table1
group by id, substring(some_date, 1, 7) 

See this fiddle, albeit MySQL but window functions also work in BQ.
